# Visual Studio 2017 C++ exception message box

Tags: visual-c++

I try to show an exception (or error code) in C++ with visual studio 2017 when a crash occurs.

For example, the following codes does not show any dialog(message box).

```
int* p = 0;
*p = 10;
```

or

```
throw std::exception("some error");
```

Thus, I cannot attach it with *just in time debugger*.
In fact, the second code shows a dialog but it is not what I want.

---

UPDATE

Windows 10 does not support the WER dialog any more. - [link](https://superuser.com/a/1349113/56135)
(link is provided by Hans Passant)

Comment: Using _undefined behavior_ doesn't guarantee that an exception is thrown. Well, the behavior is simply undefined , anything can happen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you have misunderstand. Even if I throw an exception like _throw std::exception("some error");_ there is no dialog(message box). I think that it is because of the setting or revision of visual studio 2017. So I ask it. thanks.

Comment: Show a [mcve] of what you're doing please. ATM there's only _undefined behavior_ called, no exception throw is shown. By default, if you throw an exception, the dialog box should be shown if it's not caught anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just write the following codes in main function. __int * p = 0; *p = 10; throw std::exception("some error");__. If I write only this code __throw std::exception("some error");__, the dialog box is shown. thanks.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I want to the dialog box which contains __debug__ button, but I cannot find how I handle it. Could you help me?

Comment: I am not sure, but that should be there by default also. Can you please [edit] your question as suggested, and include a screenshot of the dialog box shown.

Comment: Win10 no longer shows the WER dialog when an app crashes, it only adds an entry to the Application event log.  You definitely want to switch it into "programmer mode" so you can see these kind of mishaps, [look here](https://superuser.com/a/1349113/56135).

Answer (score -1):

Undefined.
You should also note:
If the given example is complete (no further use of p), an exception might occur, but in release mode the code may be optimized. In this case, there would be no message at all.